# JQuery works when pasted into console but not on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does this not work on page load, but when I paste the jquery into the console on my page it works.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Alex Cory</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-custom">
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="src/app.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.page-scroll a').bind('click', function(event) {
          console.log('CLICKED BUTTON! ^_^');
          event.preventDefault();
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the element in question `$('.page-scroll a')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by how your webpage seems to be set up, I suspect you're injecting your content into the page from:

```
<script src="src/app.js"></script>
```

since there's no actual content in the code itself.

When this is the case, it's because when the page loads and `$(document).ready()` fires, `$('.page-scroll a')` returns `null` because it's not rendered into the DOM yet, to put it simply.

To solve this issue, you need to attach your event handler to an element that is going to be rendered into the page when it loads. The `body` tag is good for this example, and we want to listen for `.page-scroll a` to be clicked using [jQuery's on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method:

```
// We attach a click event listener to the body element
// and we try to track when .page-scroll a is clicked 
$('body').on('click', '.page-scroll a' function(event) {
  console.log('CLICKED BUTTON! ^_^');
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

This works because since the event handler is attached to the body, each time something is clicked on the web page, it checks to see if `.page-scroll a` is clicked, rather than before you were trying to attach an event handler to an element that didn't exist yet.

Comment: awesome answer! Worked after spending close to a day figuring why it wouldn't work for me. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

Your anchor must be created after DOM is ready. So you should bind click to parent element, for example:

```
$('body').on('click', '.page-scroll a', function(e) {....});
```

That way, no matter when the anchor was created, whenever one clicks body and target is `.page-scroll a` the function will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

From JQuery Documentation

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements. Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in the jQuery object, so those elements must exist at the point the call to .bind() occurs. For more flexible event binding, see the discussion of event delegation in .on() or .delegate().

So you use `JQuery.on()` method

why does your code console is precisely because there is already the elemente

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you want to call a function while the DOM is not yet ready.

insert into the body tag

```
//link to the script file here
<body         onload="enterHereYourFunctionYouWantToLoad () " >
```

this will load your function and that particular function will run when the page is loaded.